# Laravel, SQL Server Distinct comma delimited list

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel

So i have a table looks like this

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | X |
| 2 | Y |

And I want my select in laravel to get result like
$list ->
1: A,B,C
2: X,Y

what I do is:

```
$list =  DB::table('mytable')
            ->select('ID', DB::raw('group_concat(name) as names'))
            ->groupBy('ID')
            ->get();
```

i also already tried

```
$list =  DB::table('mytable')
            ->select('ID', DB::raw('STRING_AGG(Names,",") as Names'))
            ->groupBy('ID')
            ->get();
```

but those codes proceed with same error

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]'GROUP_CONCAT or STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Can anyone advise how I would make this result?

what I do now for fast result is create view table like this

```
SELECT a.id, Names = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Name
           FROM mytable b 
           WHERE b.id = a.id 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') FROM mytable a
```

but still wanted result in laravel, I hope anyone can help

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post code in your question.

Comment: what i do is $list =  DB::table('mytable')
            ->select('ID', DB::raw('group_concat(name) as names'))
            ->groupBy('ID')

Comment: Next time please post code with questions. People think you haven’t done anything about your problem and downvote the question. Stack overflow does not accept [“send me teh codez”](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/plz-email-me-teh-codez) questions.

Comment: thanks for the advice and sorry for that